# how to connect crystalreportviewer with database?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

i have a sql table name `Patient_Detail` and i want to report it with crystal report, but is ERROR is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, At `rd.Load("C:\Users.....`

```
Dim dap As SqlDataAdapter
Dim dat As DataTable
Dim bds As BindingSource
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim rd As ReportDocument
Private Sub Report_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cn.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    dap = New SqlAdapter
    ds = New DataSet
    rs = New ReportDocument
    cmd.Connection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Patient_Detail"
    dap.SelectCommand = cmd
    dap.Fill(ds, "Patient_Detail")

    rd.Load("C:\Users\Hou Chandara\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\MyReport.rpt")

    rd.SetDataSource(ds)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    cn.Close()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set rd first. 
rd = new ReportDocument()

or in declaration

Dim rd As New ReportDocument